# Battery charging by vibration energy harvesting (LTC-3588) - how to wire?

Tags: piezo, energy-harvesting

I would like to harvest energy to keep a LFP battery charged (for a BLE device which has VERY little consumption). The battery already lasts several months, but since the device will be closed/sealed it should last literally "forever".

I have choosen some piezo elements and a LTC-3588 board, have looked at some drawings and datasheets but I am very uncertain how to wire it (please excuse I am not into electronics) correctly, this is what I have tried:

[image]

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Don't.  The [LTC-3588](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/35881fc.pdf) is intended to work with a capacitor for storage, not with a lithium cell.

Comment: but the application examples of LTC-3588 lists "low power battery charging". I am confused.

Comment: Where do you see that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: datasheet, first page: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/35882fc.pdf

Comment: I'd take that to mean that it can be used to collect energy to feed to a charger circuit.  The LTC-3588 itself doesn't have any of the circuitry you'd need to safely charge a lithium cell.

Comment: as far as I know, LFP (not LIPO!) can be charged by supplying constant voltage, even if this is not the best way to charge these cells, they don't "care". especially if they are protected against overcharging. so I am still confused why this is not possible with LTC-3588?

Answer (score 1):

You still need a battery charger, though:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjqniF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

> the application examples of LTC-3588 lists "low power battery charging"

Yes. Because LTC3588 is just a power source. You can use it to do anything, including charging a battery. But to charge a battery safely you need a charger, not merely a power source.

Comment: thank you Kuba, what would be an appropriate type of C1 for LFP charging?

Comment: Something with low self-discharge at maximum operating temperature, and enough capacitance to let the charger stay on long enough not to waste too much energy while turning on. The charger needs an under-voltage lockout function, with external feedback network to set the turn-on voltage. The charger should stay off when the capacitor voltage is below a reasonable minimum. Probably 6V would be reasonable - you’ll have to see how long the charger can stay on when the capacitor is charged to that voltage, vs. capacitance, and choose accordingly.